# Too much vertices

Tags: word-usage

I thought that one would write **too many vertices** but after seing **too much vertices** written somewhere, I checked on Google:

- **too many vertices** yields 17,300 results
- **too much vertices** yields 10,800 results

A lot of people seem to be using **much** even though vertices can be counted. Hence my question:

Is **too much vertices** correct?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: If you search for them with quotes around them (forcing Google to find the exact phrase), "too many vertices" returns 178000 results and "too much vertices" returns 16000. "much" is wrong and sounds really odd.

Comment: @MillieSmith Yes, you must, must, must use quotes when searching for phrases, like this. Searching without quotes essentially just asks Google to find pages that contain both the word "much" and the word "vertex".

Comment: @MillieSmith: I think the OP [searched with quotes](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22too+many+vertices%22). I get a disappointing 17,300 results as well for _too many_. I wonder where your google found the extra 150k+?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you page through the Google results for [*"too much vertices"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too%20much%20vertices%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22too%20much%20vertices%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.3656j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22too%20much%20vertices%22&start=60) you'll find it peters out at *Page 7 of about **69** results* (or considerably earlier if you've configured for more results per page).

If you do the same with [*"too many vertices"*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22too%20much%20vertices%22&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB569GB569&oq=%22too%20much%20vertices%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.65257j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22too%20many%20vertices%22&start=70) you'll find it gets to *Page 7 of about **186,000** results*.

This is just a quirk of Google's indexing system (which initially is significantly biased in respect of how common each individual word is (or each consecutive word-pair, in a longer search string). In reality, since *vertexes/vertices* are plural forms of a "countable" noun, ***much*** is invalid here, and only ***many*** is correct.

Comment: +1 There's also the fact that *much* and *vertices* may be in different sentences too!

Comment: @Araucaria Agreed. I just googled them with quotes and "too many vertices" has way more results.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but this omission is relevant: If you go about 22 pages into google for "too many vertices" it also stops and mentions there are 217 displayed results.

Comment: Google seems to be broken, because it refuses to give me more than 17,300 results for _too many vertices_ - even on your link. It seems Google has removed some 150,000+ instances of that phrase from the interwebs in the last 19 hours - or my Google is broken. I want a new one.

Comment: @Dennis: I don't know how Google decides the maximum results it'll return, but they massively reduced the limit a couple of years ago. Even if you search for just the word **and** it stops at 343, but I figure there's at least *some* "meaning" to the fact of it petering out after less than 70 results.

Answer (score 8):

Your first impulse is correct: *vertices* is the plural of *vertex* and requires a 'count' modifier: *too many*, not *too much*.

The lesson in this is **never, *ever*** trust those numbers that Google reports. They are pure guesses, based on a sampling algorithm which is wholly unreliable. In fact, if you start paging through the actual hits you will find that Google can actually show there are only 150 and more than half of those are duplicates.

Comment: That is just a variant of the classic "Don't use a statistics result when you do not know or understand it's math" I think. If you do, the Google counts can be very useful.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I would be pleased to learn what those 'counts' are useful for, and what are they in fact 'counting'.

Comment: The main point is to not see them as "counts" as in numbers of specified items, but use them as measures of some aspect of something. We do not know the "definition" of the measures, so we can not compare them to anything else, strictly speaking. But we can compare the measures to other measures of the same kind - which tells us something about the relation of two items, like the frequency of occurrence of two ngram. It can only be used in a relative way. But that can be very useful!

Comment: @Volker But the problem I think everybody who's tried to work with those values as indices to use is that we *cannot* rely on relative magnitudes to be meaningful either.

Answer (score 3):

Your first instinct is right: *vertices* are countable, therefore they use *many* as a quantifier, not *much*.

A better way to check usage tendencies is Google's Ngram Viewer.  We can see that "many vertices" is a phrase in use (increasing in use over the last century or so), while "much vertices" doesn't even show up in their corpus of English works.  Here's the result from the [Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many%20vertices%2Cmuch%20vertices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20vertices%3B%2Cc0) I performed:
[image: ngram search for 'much vertices' and 'many vertices']

As you can see, there's an error message at the top:

> Ngrams not found: much vertices

Answer (score 2):

Much/many depends on number - singular/plural.
One vertex, many vertices.

e.g. much money: many coins.

imo, anything else is incorrect.